# Controller scope object changes not reflected in directive $watch callback

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a controller that has an object on its scope: `$scope.objToTrack`.
I have a directive that is inside a nested view that $watches for changes to that object.
It has isolate scope, but `objToTrack` is set as `=` so that it can be watched.

When I click the directive, it calls an expression that is a method on the controller which changes `objToTrack`.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k4PcXqGPeoulsopHpTKR?p=preview) to illustrate my setup.

The problem is that `objToTrack` $watch callback isn't fired, although the object is changed.
If you switch between Test1 and Test2 states, changes made to `objToTrack` are visible. It's just that I don't understand why it doesn't work right away on click.

Thanks.

Comment: directive scope isn't set to `=` in demo. Also curious why don't use `ng-click` instead of own event handlers. Have to use `$apply` whenever you change scope with external event handlers or angular doesn't know of change

Comment: The code snippet is a demo, the *real* directive does more than that.

Answer (score 3):

To answer question...if you bind your own event handlers to an element, and change angular scope within that event handler you need to call `$apply` so angular is made aware of the change and can run a digest

Example You have:

```
element.on('click',function(){
       scope.onClick({number:RNG.int(200,300)});
});
```

Would need to be changed to:

```
element.on('click',function(){
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.onClick({number:RNG.int(200,300)});
     });
});
```

It is a lot simpler if you use event directives already provided by angular. In this case you are writing considerable amount of extra code vs using `ng-click`. It also makes testing a lot easier when you stay within angular as much as possible

Comment: The plunkr works with $apply, but the app I'm working on does not. It's odd. Especially the fact that if I use `@` instead of `=` I do get live updates inside the directive.

Comment: don't think `jQuery` like methods...just use `ng-clcik`. Let angular handle the DOM

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. The directive touches the DOM on click before calling the method on the controller. The Plunkr is much simplified.

Comment: no, i mean majority of time there is no need to add own event handlers

Comment: I agree, but I have to pass data to the controller method and I'm not sure I can do that with ngClick.

Comment: why not, you already have the controller method...just bind that to ng-clcik directly

Comment: Dynamic data determined from inside directive at click time I mean.

Comment: doesn't make any sense... can wrap a `jQlite ( angular.element)` handler around the dynamic data...no different wrapping a function bound to ng-clcik around it....

Comment: keep in mind that the `ng-click` function can be scoped in the directive

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to pass an object into your directive you should not use curly braces. 
In html, use `obj-to-track="objToTrack"`, instead of `obj-to-track="{{objToTrack}}"`. 
Like this:

```
<div simple-directive obj-to-track="objToTrack" class="directive"></div>
```

And in directive.js: use '=' for bi-directional binding of the objToTrack. 
Like this:

```
scope:{
  objToTrack:'='
}
```

Comment: That was a mistake, I gave the wrong link. I am using `=` without curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

In your "test*.html" files, replace "on-click" by "ng-click".

"on-click" doesn't look in your current controller, "ng-click" does.

Comment: directive already is passing `onClick` into isolated scope, so it is available. Difference is more to do with `$apply` doesn't need to be called with `ng-clcik`